# MediaRecorder videos longer than a few seconds don't play back

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-video, web-mediarecorder

I'd like to record a video in the browser and then play it back for the user. I'm currently using the MediaRecorder API (only available in Firefox for now) to do this. It works fine for videos shorter than a few seconds, but otherwise the video doesn't show up at all.

There are no errors in the console or similar, and I couldn't find anything about any file size limitations in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder).

Here's the code I'm using (Firefox only):

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <button id="start">Start</button>
  <button id="stop">Stop</button>
  <video id="player" src="" width="300" height="300" autoplay></video>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
var record = document.getElementById('start');
var stop = document.getElementById('stop');
var video = document.getElementById('player');

var constraints = {video: true};

var onSuccess = function(stream) {
  var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

  record.onclick = function() {
    mediaRecorder.start();
  }

  stop.onclick = function() {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
  }

  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {    
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.data);
  }
};

var onError = function(err) {
  console.log('The following error occured: ' + err);
}

navigator.mozGetUserMedia(constraints, onSuccess, onError);
```

On Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGqKgE

Is this a bug/browser issue? Are there any limitations to this API that I'm not aware of?

Comment: do you get any errors if you use the mediaRecorder.onerror handler?

Comment: @K3N nope, I tried that but there are no errors.